# How do you change x-axis labels in excel?

Tags: excel

Right now, the x-axis labels for my plot is: 0,2,4,6,8,10.

I want to change it to years: 2013, 2014, 2015, etc...

How would I do this?

Comment: put years in your source data?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming a lot here, but you should specify the category names for the axis. For example:

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).CategoryNames = Range("A2:A25")
```